# Swift Uploading video to Firebase and play it in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, avplayer

I'm trying to upload a video selected from the library to firebase storage and then getting the url associated to the video and playing it in a tableviewcell by clicking on a play button.

The way I am uploading the file is:

```
func postVideo(userId: String) {
    self.progressBar.isHidden = false
    let compressedURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + NSUUID().uuidString + ".mov")
    VideoOperation.compressVideo(inputURL: videoUrlPassed!, outputURL: compressedURL, handler: { (exportSession) in
        guard let session = exportSession else {return}
        let compressedVideoUrl = session.outputURL
        let videoIdString = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Configuration.STORAGE_MAIN_REF).child("posts").child("videos").child(userId).child(videoIdString + ".mov")
        let uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(from: compressedVideoUrl!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                ProgressHUD.showError(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            let videoUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
    })
}
```

I have then created a Model to download the information

```
extension Post {
static func videoPost(dictionary: [String:AnyObject]) -> Post {
    let post = Post()
    post._caption = dictionary["caption"] as? String
    post._videoUrl = dictionary["videoUrl"] as? String
    post._videoThumbUrl = dictionary["videoThumbUrl"] as? String
    post._isVideo = dictionary["isVideo"] as? Bool
    return post
}
```

and in the controller where i have the tableview i load the info in viewdidload:

```
func loadPosts() {
    Database.database().reference().child("posts").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            let newPhotoPost = Post.photoPost(dictionary: dict)

            if !newPhotoPost.isVideo {
                self.posts.append(newPhotoPost)
            } else {
                let newVideoPost = Post.videoPost(dictionary: dict)
                self.posts.append(newVideoPost)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Then in cellForRowAt i create the player:

```
if post.isVideo {
        let url = URL(string: post.videoUrl)
        cell.createPlayer(url: url!)
    }
```

here's the func to create the player in my tableviewcell:

```
    func createPlayer(url: URL) {
    self.playerCell = AVPlayer(url: url)
    self.playerLayerCell = AVPlayerLayer(player: playerCell)
    self.playerLayerCell?.frame = videoContainerView.bounds
    self.playerLayerCell?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    self.videoContainerView.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayerCell!, at: 0)
}
```

The video is playing but i have two issue:
1) when i dismiss the controller the video keeps playing
2) And this the most annoying one i get this error:

```
CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
class = inet;
"m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
"r_Attributes" = 1;
sync = syna;
```

}

If i tap on play button the video is playing but i'm really not able to understand what that error is!

I would be really glad if anybody could help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When tableview cellForRow is called everytime the AVPlayer is reinitialized with the url provided from the model object. When new cells are initialized when scrolling through the tableview new AVPlayer instances are created for the new cells.

Error 1: You can stop the player by calling didEndDisplayingCell delegate method of the UItableview and stop the player is the player's rate is not equal to 0.

```
if (cell.player.rate != 0) && (cell.player.error == nil)) {
     // player is playing
     cell.player = nil;
}
```

Error 2: I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Thx for the answer... at least i can try to fix one error.... for the second i got still no clue either... seems like a permission error... but the user is logged and the permission are set correctly.... and plus... the video is actually playing...